# Example VU Meter using Windows Media Graph API?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

The question says it all. 
I would like to create the simplest possible VU-meter example, using the new UWP Media Graph API, but so far, I haven't found any good examples.

There are a couple of questions in this:

1. I am using the "normal" code to enumerate my microphones:

   ```
   var deviceInformation = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(MediaDevice.GetAudioCaptureSelector());
   ```

However, when I create an **AudioGraphSettings** object, I cannot find a property to pass the device found. There is a property named **DesiredRenderDeviceAudioProcessing** however, I'm not sure I understand it's purpose.

2. Following the best examples I've found, I proceed to create a graph, and use that to get an **InputNode** as such:

   ```
   var creationResult = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

   if (creationResult.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
       return;

   _graph = creationResult.Graph;

   var inputNodeCreationResult = await _graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCategory.Media);

   if (inputNodeCreationResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
   {
       DestroyGraph();
       return;
   }

   _inputNode = inputNodeCreationResult.DeviceInputNode;
   ```

From here on, I'm running blind. Not finding any good tutorials, examples or documentation to help me.

I am only interested in sound level (dB), not the waveform. Is there anyone that can help me complete this, or point me to some decent documentation?

Answer (score 1):

"Scenario 2: Device Capture" from the [Windows Universal Samples - Audio Creation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation/) project should provide some guidance. From your code it looks like you're on track. Might just be a case of adding the following:

```
_frameOutputNode = _graph.CreateFrameOutputNode();
_frameOutputNode.Start();

_graph.QuantumProcessed += Graph_QuantumProcessed;
_graph.Start();
```

And using the `Graph_QuantumProcessed` callback to analyse the `AudioFrame` provided by a call to `_frameOutputNode.GetFrame()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It did help to some extent, but I'm starting to understand that creating a simple VU meter is too complex for comfort. I want to use this as part of an IoT demo solution, and thought that getting noise level from a microphone would be an easy-to-understand scenario, but it is already becoming so complicated that I might just go for something else. I was able to get a frame, but now I need to decode it in order to find what I need.